# Xpath operators for WP All Import

Tags: xpath, woocommerce, wpallimport

I want to import all products filtering these they applied all 3 criteria:

**1)** they are in stock (DIM)

**2)** stock is more than 3 pcs (`stock_indicator`)

**3)** and they belong to one (any) of these groups 1 or 4

I want all 3 criteria, but in 3rd any of these options

i.e.:
`/product[dim1[1] = "1" and stock_indicator[1] > 3 and group[1] = "1" or group/category/id[1] = "4"]`

The above does not returns any product, like no product have all these requirements.

What am I doing wrong?

Dim = availability

XML sample:
[image]

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. Hard to tell you what's wrong if we can't see the structure of your XML file.

Comment: @E.Wiest i added the sample on initial post

Comment: It would be nice to get the data sample as text not as screenshot, moreover the above example misses to provide a complete `item`

Answer (score 2):

```
/product[dim1[1] = "1" and stock_indicator[1] > 3 and group[1] = "1" or group/category/id[1] = "4"]
```

First of all your XPath assumes that all `product` elements are at root level, which would not make for a well-formed XML document; the all should be wrapped in some element.

If that is no problem in your environment (since we do not know the whole setup from your question) probably the most prominent problem in your XPath is that you try to compare the value of `stock_indicator` against a `xs:integer` but in fact your data sample encodes them as `xs:string`.

Consequently

```
stock_indicator[1] > 3
```

will always return `false`…

Try

```
stock_indicator[1]/number() > 3
```

or

```
number(stock_indicator[1]) > 3
```

instead.

Nevertheless depending on the data structure (e.g. multiple `stock_indicator`elements in one `product` [whatever that might mean]) this could return false positives.

Comment: Nice post. WP All Import doesn't support XPath 2.0 expressions though. `number` function is also not necessary to evaluate the nodes.

Comment: Τhank you for your reply, i will check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XPath to filter the products :

```
//product[availability="1"][stock_indicator>3][group/id=1 or group/id=4]
```

- `//` at the beginning as stated by @Benjamin W. Bohl to catch all products
- `availability` is used instead of "Dim"
- cleaner syntax used for predicates
- no position indexes used (`[1]`) assuming you only have 1 `availability`, 1 `stock_indicator`, 1 `id` per `group` in each `product`

[XML](https://pastebin.com/Ar7wDfvS) used to test.

XPath :

[image: XP]

XML is filtered (2 of the 4 products fulfill the conditions) :

[image: FilterXML]

Comment: Τhank you for your reply, i will check them